# Can I set Sleep timeout using variable in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

Here actually I have multiple Testcase in Robot Framework, in this we have declare Sleep Method multiple however in our Testcase we have requirement not to put timeout value in Sleep and they want to use to have using Variable

for eg:

```
Sleep 2s
```

In this case 2s should be declare using variable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, easily:

```
${seconds}=     Set Variable    4
Sleep    ${seconds}s
```

If you are setting the value in the Variables section, naturally you have to follow the format there:

```
*** Variables *** 
${seconds}=         4
```

You'd better make sure the value is actually a number - or the sleep keyboard will fail, something like this:

```
${rc}    ${seconds}=     Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Convert To Integer    ${seconds}
Run Keyword If    "${seconds}"! = 'PASS'    Fail    The value is not a number
```

Comment: i am getting error message : ValueError: Invalid time string 'Set Variable 4s'.

Comment: Where are you setting the value - in a test case/keyword, or in the `*** Variables ***` section?

Comment: I am setting ${seconds}=     Set Variable    4 in Variables Section and Sleep    ${seconds}s in testcase

Comment: That's not the format used to set a value in the Variables section; I'll put that in the answer.